# Cause a second namespace to choose which third namespace to load

Tags: matrix, clojure, dependencies

Namespace `foo` defines a set of functions defined in terms of arithmetic operators.  These are either scalar arithmetic operators or matrix arithmetic operators, depending on whether `foo` `require`s the `scalar-arithmetic` or `matrix-arithmetic` namespace.  (There's not a lot of code in foo.cljc, but it's enough that it would be silly to duplicate it.  I know that core.matrix--which is what `matrix-arithmetic` is defined in terms of--can handle raw scalars, but in that case it's a lot slower than Clojure's built-in arithmetic, and speed of `foo`'s functions will matter for my application.)

Namespace `bar-s` needs scalar arithmetic.  Namespace `bar-m` needs matrix arithmetic.  Both namespaces need the functions defined in namespace `foo`, but `bar-s` needs those functions in their scalar versions, while `bar-m` needs them in their matrix form.  We can assume that I will only load one of `bar-m` and `bar-s` in the same session.  (If I don't need this assumption, that's great, but I can live with it.)

I'm trying to figure out the best way for `bar-s` or `bar-m` to specify which version of `foo` to load--that is, how to force `foo` to load the `scalar-arithmetic` namespace, or to load the `matrix-arithmetic` namespace.  (Or: If there's a better, very different way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, I'm happy to rethink it.)

Currently, this is what I'm doing.  It seems to work: I have another namespace, `config`, in which I define an atom containing a boolean.  In `bar-s` or `bar-m`, I reset this atom to a value that will select the arithmetic implementation I want, *and then* I `require` `foo`.  `foo` checks the atom, and then `require`s either `scalar-arithmetic` or `matrix-arithmetic`, depending on the atom.

This might be the best way to do what I want, but it's a strange method, and I wonder whether there's a better way.  I *think* that if I only reset the atom at the beginning of a session, I won't have problems, but I'm worried that there are gotchas I don't know about.

Here's a toy version of the setup:

```
(ns scalar-arithmetic)

(defmacro m* [x y] `(* ~x ~y))
;; Using (def m* *) instead would lose Clojure's special optimizations for *

(defmacro inv [x]  `(/ 1.0 ~x))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(ns matrix-arithmetic
  (:require [clojure.core.matrix :as mx]))

(def m* mx/mmul)     ; matrix multiplication
(def inv mx/inverse) ; matrix inverse

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(ns foo
  (require [config]))

(if @config/use-core-matrix
   (require '[matrix-arithmetic :refer [m* inv]])
   (require '[scalar-arithmetic :refer [m* inv]]))

(defn fooey [r s] (m* r (inv s))) ; could have either scalar or matrix meaning

;; The next two namespaces would not both be loaded in the same session.

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(ns bar-s
   (require [config]))

(reset! config/use-core-matrix true)
(require '[foo])

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(ns bar-m
  (require [foo])) ;; default value of use-core-matrix is false, so this is enough.
```

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29034513/3100284) might help.

Comment: This seems like a canonical multimethods use case. Why not use multimethods?

Comment: @JonahB, you may be right.  Not sure.  I honestly hadn't thought about multimethods, but should have.  Would that be as fast as plain Clojure `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/`?  At present I am defining the scalar operators as macros so that I lose no speed compared to raw math operators.  (This is for performance-critical code.)  I can run benchmarks, but given my understanding of multimethods, I think they should be slower.  I've already established that protocols would be slower, I believe.

Comment: @nrako, thanks for the pointer to that answer.  Seems like it should be relevant, but I don't yet see how to use ideas from that answer.  I certainly wouldn't want to do a namespace load on every operator call.

Comment: For performance-sensitive operations, type based dispatch using protocols should be fastest. All jvm dispatch has to be typed, protocols provide hints and allow for caching that ordinary functions cannot. May be worth sharing benchmarks for feedback. For use case above, see core.matrix with-implementation.

Comment: @JonahB, core.matrix works just fine with raw scalars, but scalar arithmetic with its `add`, `sub`, and `mmul` or `mul` is a lot [slower than clojure.core's `+`, `-`, and `*`](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/numerical-clojure/RemtazqhHyc/TITcZy4FDQAJ).   Since core.matrix does this with protocols, I assume me doing it with protocols won't help.  clojure.core arithmetic functions have special optimizations.  That's why I use macros for scalar arithmetic: `(def m* *)` is a lot slower (see link).  Full benchmarks don't seem relevant with a fundamental difference for *, +, -.